# Secondary HDD mounting in /media/username under wrong folder name

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I have my Ubuntu installed on an SSD, and a secondary HDD called Earth that I've set to automatically mount at startup. The thing is, when it mounts, the folder is labelled "Earth1" instead of "Earth". There is still a folder in /media/username called "Earth" but when I attempt to open it, it gives the error:

> This location could not be displayed. You do not have the permissions necessary to view the contents of 'Earth'.

So right now a whole bunch of programs are trying to access files in /media/username/Earth but returning errors.

This has been happening since I had a problem with Unity and had to reset some of my user settings. I'm currently logged in as admin, and I've checked the startup command and everything's fine there.

---

#### Update 2017-10-31 (for future reference)

I was using Startup Applications to mount Earth (BTW, Startup Applications runs *at login*, not at boot). Based on [subin's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/543437/301745), I switched to using the Disks utility, which saves its config to the /etc/fstab file (which tells the system to mount partitions at boot), and that worked fine. The fstab entry specified the mount point.

Comment: Related: [Why does the mount point keeps changing, and how can I prevent it?](https://askubuntu.com/q/2126/301745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correcting the line in /etc/fstab should help. If you have used the disk utility to setup the auto mount options, you should see a line which contains the mount point (here `/media/username/Earth`) Check if the line exists. If not, use the disk utility to set it up again. Looks like the directory /media/username/Earth exists and it is not specified as the mount point, so when the auto mounter sees the directory `Earth` already existing, it creates another directory `Earth1` and mounts the partition there.

Comment: This fixed it, indirectly! I was using Startup Applications to mount the disk at boot. I switched to the disk utility and that fixed the issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set user permissions by chowning the earth volume to your user name. This sounds complicated but is insanely easy & teaches you some CLI skills. (Not to be confused with chmod.)

Comment: After some time and experience, I ended up adding mount options to the fstab to the same effect: `uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=022,users`. I'm not sure if `chown` would have worked since Earth was an NTFS partition.

Answer (score 0):

You can try changing it in /etc/fstab or making a folder in on the drive as root and then chowning it to your user.
EDIT: I tried this a while ago and it worked perfectly after using fstab to mount it to the right place and  chowning a folder to fix the user problems.

Comment: Does this answer add anything new? I mean, subin already mentioned editing fstab, and fleamour already mentioned chowning.

Comment: i meant to add that i had a similar problem and it fixed it for me

Comment: What fixed it for you? You wrote two different options. Also what did you change in fstab?

Comment: Changing it in fstab made it mount to the right place and chowning it fixed the user problem. What I mean is it took both.

Comment: Ah, I see. Please edit that into the answer. Thanks!